# Adding style to java script string

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a button that generates random text in JavaScript. I would like to style the randomly generated text to be below the button, centered, and have the following color: #8a2be2.

```js
   
<!-- arrays -->
function GetValue()
{
    var myarray= new Array();

 myarray[0]="The calcium in our bones and the iron in our blood come from ancient explosions of giant stars."
 myarray[1]="The Chinese giant salamander can grow to be 6 feet (1.8 m) long, making it the largest salamander in the world."
<!--END--> 
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    //alert(random);
    document.getElementById("fact button").innerHTML=random;
}
```

```html
<input  type="button" id="fact_button" value="Fact Button" onclick="GetValue();" />
<p id="fact button" ></p>
<h2 class="h2">click fact button for an amazing fact!</class> </h2>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to apply styles and what is it you want to style? The button or the string because your question appears to be a little confusing to what it is you want to style...

Comment: you can add css styles, what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: yes i added a CSS check it out

Answer (score 1):

add text inside p or div element as bellow

```js
   
<!-- arrays -->
function GetValue()
{
    var myarray= new Array();

 myarray[0]="<p style='color:#8a2be2'>The calcium in our bones and the iron in our blood come from ancient explosions of giant stars.</p>"
 myarray[1]="<p style='color:#8a2be2'>The Chinese giant salamander can grow to be 6 feet (1.8 m) long, making it the largest salamander in the world.</p>"
<!--END--> 
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    //alert(random);
    document.getElementById("fact button").innerHTML=random;
}
```

```html
<input  type="button" id="fact_button" value="Fact Button" onclick="GetValue();" />
<p id="fact button" ></p>
<h2 class="h2">click fact button for an amazing fact!</class> </h2>
```

Comment: So that would be a paragraph within a paragraph.... why not just style the first paragraph rather than nesting them to apply styles... your method doesn't make sense.

Comment: also you can change style by code or add class for the paragraph

Answer (score 1):

```js
   
<!-- arrays -->
function GetValue()
{
    var myarray= new Array();

 myarray[0]="The calcium in our bones and the iron in our blood come from ancient explosions of giant stars."
 myarray[1]="The Chinese giant salamander can grow to be 6 feet (1.8 m) long, making it the largest salamander in the world."
<!--END--> 
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    //alert(random);
    document.getElementById("fact button").innerHTML=random;
}
```

```html
<input  type="button" id="fact_button" value="Fact Button" onclick="GetValue();" />
<p id="fact button" style="text-align:center;color:#8a2be2;"></p>
<h2 class="h2">click fact button for an amazing fact!</class> </h2>
```

If you want to apply css styles, you can simply add them to the `<p>` tag as shown above or import an external stylesheet.

Comment: If you could accept the answer, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.getElementById("fact button").style.[property] = "[value]";` to set different styles. The following code shows how you can achieve your desired goal.

```js
   
<!-- arrays -->
function GetValue()
{
    var myarray= new Array();

 myarray[0]="The calcium in our bones and the iron in our blood come from ancient explosions of giant stars."
 myarray[1]="The Chinese giant salamander can grow to be 6 feet (1.8 m) long, making it the largest salamander in the world."
<!--END--> 
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    //alert(random);
    document.getElementById("fact button").innerHTML=random;
    document.getElementById("fact button").style.color ="#8a2be2";
    document.getElementById("fact button").style.textAlign="center";
}
```

```html
<input  type="button" id="fact_button" value="Fact Button" onclick="GetValue();" />
<p id="fact button" ></p>
<h2 class="h2">click fact button for an amazing fact!</class> </h2>
```